# Passing string arrays from COM to C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, com-interop, safearray

I need to access C# methods in a COM dll via COM-like interface. One of the method requires an array of strings to be passed as input.

Am creating a SAFEARRAY and passing it to the COM Interop. However, this does not seem to be working, as I see an exception in the interop layer. (System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException).

Obviously, there seems to be a difference in type being expected.

Pasting the code here:

### C# method to be invoked:

```
public long DoIt3(int nFiles, string[] fileNames);
```

### C++ code invoking the same:

```
int _tmain()
{
TCHAR *fileNames[128] = { TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\RTC.NET"),
                          TEXT("C:\\KIRAN\\Work\\RFT"), TEXT(".\\bin\\Debug") };

SAFEARRAY *pSA = CreateSafeStringArray(3, fileNames);

_tprintf(TEXT("%d"), pIManaged->DoIt3(3, pSA));

SafeArrayDestroy(pSA);
}

static SAFEARRAY *CreateSafeStringArray(long nElements, TCHAR *elements[])
{
SAFEARRAYBOUND saBound[1];

saBound[0].cElements = nElements;
saBound[0].lLbound = 0;

SAFEARRAY *pSA = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, saBound);

if (pSA == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}

for (int ix = 0; ix < nElements; ix++)
{
    VARIANT v;

    VariantInit(&v);

    v.vt = VT_BSTR;
    v.bstrVal = elements[ix];

    long rgIndicies[1];

    rgIndicies[0] = ix + saBound[0].lLbound;

    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayPutElement(pSA, rgIndicies, &v);

    _tprintf(TEXT("%d"), hr);

    VariantClear(&v);
}

return pSA;
}
```

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How are you generating the Runtime Callible Wrapper for the ComObject is the c# code ?

Comment: Pretty unclear how you are invoking the C# method.  But you created an object[], not a string[].  Pass VT_BSTR to SafeArrayCreate() and adjust the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: Not sure about C++, but to get a VBA client to call a C# CCW, the only way I got it working was to declare the string array argument as `ref`: `public long DoIt3(int nFiles, ref string[] fileNames);`

Comment: @Joe That was because VBA clients *always* pass variant parameters as VT_BYREF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! The following code works:

```
static SAFEARRAY *CreateSafeStringArray(long nElements, TCHAR *elements[])
{
SAFEARRAYBOUND saBound[1];

saBound[0].cElements = nElements;
saBound[0].lLbound = 0;

SAFEARRAY *pSA = SafeArrayCreate(VT_BSTR, 1, saBound);

if (pSA == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}

for (int ix = 0; ix < nElements; ix++)
{
    BSTR pData = SysAllocString(elements[ix]);

    long rgIndicies[1];

    rgIndicies[0] = saBound[0].lLbound + ix;

    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayPutElement(pSA, rgIndicies, pData);

    _tprintf(TEXT("%d"), hr);
}

return pSA;
}
```

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an array of BSTR strings, you can set the BSTR values directly on your array, and also [you need to allocate memory for your BSTR elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xda6xzx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you could use ATL/MFC CString for that:

```
...
psa = SafeArrayCreate( VT_BSTR, 1, saBound);
HRESULT hr = SafeArrayLock( psa );
//TODO: test for hr success

if (pSA == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}

for (int ix = 0; ix < nElements; ix++)
{
    long rgIndicies[1];
    rgIndicies[0] = ix + saBound[0].lLbound;
    CString tempstr(elements[ix]);

    ((BSTR*)psa->pvData)[ix] = tempstr.AllocSysString();
    _tprintf(TEXT("%d"), hr);
}

hr = SafeArrayUnlock( psa );
//TODO: test for hr success
...
```

Comment: Thanks, yms!

Will try out. But, this approach appears like achieving it through manipulating the internal fields. Is there a standard way of doing it -- may be, the arguments am passing to SafeArrayPutElement() is wrong.